# React get element dimensions from another element that is rendered at the same time

Tags: reactjs

I have a board with rectangles and connecting lines rendered at the same time. Each line needs to know the dimensions of the two rectangles it connects, which are dynamic depending on the name - so height and width of each rectangle is different.

```
export interface IRectangle {
  name: string;
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

export interface IConnectingLine {
  startingNodeName: string;
  targetNodeName: string;
}

const Board: FC<Props> = ({ rectangles, connectingLines }) => {
  const findRectangleByName = (name: string): IRectangle =>
    rectangles.find((r) => r.name === name)!

  return (
    <S.Container>
      {rectangles.map((r) => (
        <Rectangle key={r.name} {...r} />
      ))}
      {connectingLines.map((cl) => (
        <ConnectingLine
          key={`${cl.startingNodeName}-${cl.targetNodeName}`}
          startingNode={findRectangleByName(cl.startingNodeName)}
          targetNode={findRectangleByName(cl.targetNodeName)}
        />
      ))}
    </S.Container>
  )
}
```

My question is what's the best way to accomplish that. One way to do it is pass the entire rectangles props to the connecting line, have it render the rectangle offscreen (visibility hidden absolute top: -99999 left: -99999) and get the ref. However, that will mean each connecting line will render two additional rectangles just to have their dimensions. Doesn't sound very performant.

Another way would be - each rectangle would call onSetWidth(dimensions) on mount, and that will update that board's state object that will hold an object with rectangles names as keys and dimensions as values.

The problem with this approach is that every rectangle will trigger a board rerender, which also might be problematic for performance, and I'm not even sure it won't enter a recursive loop since it will rerender the rectangles again.

Any ideas?
Is there a way maybe to have the board "prerender" the rectangles and pass the dimensions to the connecting lines and the "rendering results (the actual dom outcome)" to the rectangles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you relying on the browser/DOM computing the dimensions of each rectangle, or are you computing them yourself?

Comment: DOM, I only know the name of the rectangle, not the dimensions

Comment: Well, you could grab a `ref` to each rectangle DOM element (a function ref is probably easier here) and then interrogate the DOM elements?

Comment: yes but how would you go about it? the connecting lines and the rectangles are rendered together, so at that time I don't have the refs. As I said I can use a callback on each rectangle to update the board state with an object holding the dimensions, but that would mean a rerender for each rectangle

Comment: I think that unless you know all of the facts of the layout beforehand, it'll need two renders (one when all the rectangles have settled, and one to figure out how to draw the arrows).

Comment: how would you go about it to only cause 2 renders and not one for each child?

Comment: Once you have all the refs for all of the rectangles, have the Board component figure out the arrows (maybe using e.g. https://github.com/steveruizok/perfect-arrows ? Been dying to figure out a project where to use that library :-) ) and pass the data down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232071/discussion-between-goldylucks-and-akx).